# If two tuples are close, how far apart can their products be?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

## The Question

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, fix $d \in \{2,3,4,\cdots\}$, and fix $n_1,\cdots,n_d\in\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & h (\bar y, \bar z) := \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^d y_i^{n_i} - \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^d z_i^{n_i}\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^d y_i \le  1\\ &\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^d z_i \le 1\\ & |y_i - z_i| \le \varepsilon, \quad  \forall i \in [d]\\ & y_1,\cdots,y_d \geq 0\\ & z_1,\cdots,z_d \geq 0\end{array}$$

What is the maximum?

## Some Simplifications

Suppose that we are handed some point $(\bar y,\bar z)\in[0,1]^d\times[0,1]^d$ which maximizes $h$. Notice that we can safely assume that $\sum z_i<1$, as otherwise there would be some $j$ such that $z_j\ge y_j$; we could then shrink $z_j$ slightly without breaking any of the constraints, contradicting the maximality of $h(\bar y,\bar z)$.

Now assume towards a contradiction that $\sum y_i<1$. If $y_j\le z_j$ for some $j$, then we can make $y_j$ slightly larger without breaking any of the constraints, which again contradicts maximality. So every $y_i$ is bigger than $z_i$; it follows that

$\begin{align}
\prod_{i=2}^dy_i^{n_i}\ge \prod_{i=2}^dz_i^{n_i}.
\end{align}$

Therefore, if we make $y_1$ and $z_1$ larger by the same amount, then that makes $h$ larger. But we know $\sum z_i<1$ and are assuming $\sum y_i<1$, so there is some small about we can make $y_1$ and $z_1$ larger by that doesn't break any constraints. This again contradicts maximality, so $\sum y_i=1$.

So it suffices consider two cases. In both cases the only unstated constraint is that each $y_i$ is positive and $\sum y_1=1$.

- Case A: There is some $j$ such that $y_j\le\varepsilon$. Then clearly if $\prod z_i^{n_i}\ne0$ we can just shrink $z_j$ to zero without breaking any of the constraints. So the maximum in this case occurs at the maximum of $\prod y_i^{n_i}$.
- Case B: $y_i>\varepsilon$ for every $i$. Then there's no reason for $z_i$ to be any bigger than $y_i-\varepsilon$, so it suffices to maximize $\prod y_i^{n_i}-\prod(y_i-\varepsilon)^{n_i}$.

So we just have to maximize $\prod y_i^{n_i}$ and $\prod y_i^{n_i}-\prod(y_i-\varepsilon)^{n_i}$ subject to the constraints given, and then pick the larger of the two.

## Some Special Cases

The easiest case to deal with is the one where $n_1=\cdots=n_d=1$. I'll spare you the details (this question is already long enough), but you don't even need calculus to show that if $\varepsilon\ge 1/d$ then the maximum value is $(1/d)^d$, and if $\varepsilon<1/d$ then the maximum is the larger of $\varepsilon\big(\frac{1-\varepsilon}{d-1}\big)^{d-1}$ and $(1/d)^d-(1/d-\varepsilon)^d$.

I was also able to solve this problem when $d=2=n_1$ and $n_2=1$. I'll include my solution (modulo some details) because it might be instructive for the general case.

For easy of notation, take $x=y_1$ and $w=y_2$. Let's start with Case B. Then we are trying to optimize $x^2w-(x-\varepsilon)^2(w-\varepsilon)$ subject to the constraint $x+w=1$, for $x,w\in(\varepsilon,1]$. By the method of Lagrange multipliers, if a maximum occurs at $(x,w)$ then there is some $\lambda$ such that $(x,w,\lambda)$ solves
\begin{align*}
x^2-(x-\varepsilon)^2&=\lambda\\
2xw-2(x-\varepsilon)(w-\varepsilon)&=\lambda\\
x+w&=1.
\end{align*}
This is a system of linear equations that you can easily solve; the unique solution is $x=1-\varepsilon/2$, $w=\varepsilon/2$, and $\lambda=2\varepsilon-2\varepsilon^2$. But $\varepsilon/2\not\in(\varepsilon,1]$, so $x=1-\varepsilon/2$ and $w=\varepsilon/2$ is not a valid solution in case B. Therefore, the only possible maximum when $d=2=n_1$ and $n_2=1$ comes from case A.

Thus it suffices to maximize $x^2w$ subject to $x+w=1$ and either $x$ or $w$ less than $\varepsilon$. Notice that maximizing $x^2w$ subject just to $x+w=1$ is easy; you get $x=2/3$ and $w=1/3$. So if $\varepsilon\ge1/3$, then we can just take $x=2/3$ and $w=1/3$. If $\varepsilon<1/3$, then since $x^2(1-x)$ is increasing on $[0,2/3]$ and decreasing on $[0,1/3]$, the candidate maxima for $x\in[0,\varepsilon]\cup[1-\varepsilon,1]$ are at $x=\varepsilon$ and $x=1-\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon<1/3<1/2$, clearly the maximum occurs at the latter, so the maximum value is $(1-\varepsilon)^2\varepsilon$.

To summarize, if $\varepsilon\ge1/3$ then the maximum value is $4/27$, and if $\varepsilon<1/3$ then the maximum value is $(1-\varepsilon)^2\varepsilon$.

## Closing Thoughts

My instinct is that at least Case A should be doable in general. Specifically, my plan was to figure out what the solution is without $\varepsilon$, and then reason about what the maximum should be when $\varepsilon$ is small enough to matter, just as above. A solution to Case A solves the whole problem whenever $\varepsilon>1/d$, so even if Case B is not tractable we would already be somewhere interesting.

I feel this question as stated is natural. If you replace the $\ell^1$ bound on $\bar y$ and $\bar z$ with an $\ell^\infty$ bound, then the problem becomes too easy. And if you replace the $\ell^\infty$ bound on the difference $\bar y-\bar z$ with an $\ell^1$ bound, then based on playing around with the problem I think it becomes much harder. That said, if anyone knowns a solution to the problem where we have $\sum|y_i-z_i|\le\varepsilon$ instead of $|y_i-z_i|<\varepsilon$ for each $i$, I would also be interested.

I searched the site before asking this question. Every similar question I found was either asking for a maximum over the integers (with a different upper bound on the sum than $1$, of course), or asking about the case where $n_1=1=\cdots=n_d$.

Comment: 13 views and zero votes in three days suggests that no one cares. Just in case some future soul *does* care, I'll mention that I have managed to solve Case A, and that the solution proceeds exactly as I guessed in the question. Ping me and I can provide details.

Comment: [Signomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signomial)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Looks more readable, thanks! Your "Signomial" comment also made me realize that I forgot to specify that the $n_i$ are positive integers.

Comment: Have you tried using KKT?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think so? I'm not very familiar with KKT, but based on its Wikipedia article it sounds like for any candidate maximum where all the inequality constraints are strict, the KKT method reduces to the Lagrange multiplier method. And I have tried using Lagrange multipliers for Case B. (We don't have to worry about the possibility that the inequality constraints $y_i\ge\varepsilon$ are not all strict because that is covered by the solution to Case A.)